# PHP foreach using $variable->property

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code that runs reports from $results returning from mysql query. 
The queries are relatively standard, but their total number is dynamic. So far I have static HTML where it has the same code repeated, but thats only if ok the number of queries == the number of markup repetitions.

So, I am trying to implement a new foreach loop that will determine how many "queries" there are, and only markup for each one, and then $total at the end.

To date I have had static php foreach loop like this, works well.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Year</th>
                            <th>Month</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Minimum</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Maximum</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Change</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <?php foreach ($results as $result) :
                    if ($result->id == 151){

                        echo '<tr>';
                         echo   '<td>', $result->Year, '</td>';
                         echo   '<td>', $result->Month, '</td>';
                         echo   '<td class="text-centre">', $result->name, '</td>';
                         echo   '<td class="text-right">', $result->min, '</td>';
                         echo   '<td class="text-right">', $result->max, '</td>';
                         echo   '<td class="text-right">', $result->cumulative, '</td>';
                        $thirdtotal += $result->change;
                        $total += $result->change;
                         echo '</tr>';



                    } 
                      endforeach; ?>
```

Where I am stuck is, do i put the above inside another for each loop? My thought is, if a query exists, it will have an "id" field in the array, so for the number of "id", thats how many outputs you'll get.

```
  <?php foreach ($results as $key => $value;) :
                   {

                         echo '<tr>';
                         echo  '<td>' $value, '</td>';
                         echo '</tr>';
                   } 
                  endforeach; ?>
```

This piece of test code doesnt work, am I using the key value correctly? Is it the correct approach to solve this problem and reduce the amount of php in the controller?

Thanks

Comment: This looks to be a pure PHP problem unrelated to MySQL.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: `if ($result->id == 151){` ?

Comment: The ->id ==151 line is how I am sorting them currently. Each loop is looking for a different id so it will onyl output if the ID matches. But it means I have to change the if statement every time I need to add something with a different id

Comment: Why not just select the row matching the ID instead? And how do you fetch this data, can you show the code for that?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Qirel? The query code is like this:

UNION

SELECT 
    YEAR('2017-01-01') AS Year,
    MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m')) AS Month,
    name,
value.id,
 MIN(input_value) AS min,
    MAX(input_value) AS max,
    TRUNCATE(MAX(input_value) - MIN(input_value),
        2) AS cumulative
FROM
    input_values
        JOIN
   etc etc

Sorry for bad formatting CTRL-K doesnt work in replies

Comment: In the code that doesn't work you need a comma `,` or a dot `.` before `$value`. You can find the reason in the manual for `echo`.

Comment: Thanks jh1711 fixed that with this:            
<?php foreach ($results as $key => $value) :
                   {
                        
                       
                         echo ($value->id);
                     
                          
                      

                    } 
                      endforeach; ?>

It runs, and returns the numbers of the id's